# Unity Android - Remove Caller ID permission

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-permissions, chartboost

Recently I've added two services - Chartboost and UnityAds for advertising in my ready-to-launch game. However I've noticed that the app now asks for a permission to read Caller ID data. I've searched the plugins Android Manifest and found no line of requesting this permission - I'm wondering if it is automatically added when using some special function?

I've already researched this topic and found I have no usage of

```
SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier
```

that would put this permission in the manifest.

I would appreciate any help or ideas on how to remove this permission.

Comment: Check the T&C of the ChartBoost and UnityAds, I suspect they need it so they can scrape metrics.