# Unity Android Game requests permission to read phone state but NONE of my manifests have that permission in it

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-permissions

The only permission that i see in the manifest files that i have is :

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

yet whenever i run the game on device, it asks for permission to read phone and contacts information, when i open the manifest inside Temp\StagingArea i do see the request to read phone state, here is the full manifest content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.game.name" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="2.3" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:isGame="false" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value="70418cbaf12012ef266c9d170326ef4293fef28b" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.unity.crashlytics.version" android:value="1.2.5" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.crashlytics.qualified" android:value="com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.crashlytics.unqualified" android:value="Crashlytics" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.kits" android:value="crashlytics" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.fabric.InitializationType" android:value="Automatic" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="f221d2f3-918c-4005-a864-613d5419c9b9" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

is there any solution to know the cause of this, without having to remove all plugins and add them one by one ?

Edit: 
Forgot to mention the "plugins" am using in case some of them rings a bell :

- Unity IAP
- Unity Analytics
- Unity Social
- Google AdMob Mediation (UnityAds, Vungle and AdMob)
- Crashlytics
- Games Analytics

Comment: I don't understand. Your example contains `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` - is it the line you're looking for?

Comment: sorry for not clarifying that, the full XML file is the final AndroidManifest generated automatically by Unity after merging all the Manifests i have in the project, my problem is that i cannot find that permission in the project (the files that i can edit) but it somehow ends up in the final XML file.

Comment: So you want to remove this permission that is added automatically by Unity, right? What is your Unity version?

Comment: @naXa yes! unity 2017.3.1f1

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48232560/1429387 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/31853897/1429387 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/40931058/1429387 , https://answers.unity.com/questions/987433/read-phone-state-permission-since-51.html , https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/android-read-phone-state-permission-is-added-in-the-androidmanifest-dot-xml-file-using-latest-26-dot-0-2-sdk Take a look at this questions, read comments - you may found them helpful in resolving your own problem.